# Do I need to set the FQDN as the hostname?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, nginx

I'm a bit uncertain about a few things.  I'm trying to learn a few things on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.  I have registered with Amazon Web Service's Route 53 the DNS settings for a domain of mine.  Actually the domain is registered with Godaddy.com.  So, I have brucemwhealton.us with the AWS nameservers set at Godaddy.
      First question, during installation it asks for a hostname and it suggests ubuntu which is not a FQDN.  So, it is not installed but I used 
brucemwhealton.us as a FQDN during installation.  That resolves ok.  Did I do that right, or should I have setup computer one to have a hostname that gets appended to the front of brucemwhealton.us, as in bruce.brucemwhealton.us

Related to this, if I want to install flask and django as sub-domains, such as django.brucemwhealton.us or flask.brucemwhealton.us do I just specify that in the vhosts file, if using apache or the similar file for NGINX?

Another thing that confuses me is that in some tutorials, I see internet accessible domains added to a hosts file or the hosts file.  I suppose that would make things faster for me during development, if I use the IP of my router - my public IP.  If I used my local IP for the computer running apache or Nginx, would that prevent that domain from working on the external internet?  In other words, if I put a line in the hosts file like this:

```
192.168.0.10    brucemwhealton.us
```

I didn't use my real internal IP above, just an example internal IP.  So, once I specify that in the host file will that only effect me on my local network?  My router has a rule to forward port 80 requests to the IP of the computer running apache.

With the bind9 dns server, I guess I would not need a Record Set at AWS.  That would just mean setting the DNS records at godaddy.  So, still unsure about where bind9 on Ubuntu would help.
Sorry to write so much... It boils down to a few questions:
1) what to put in the hostname file?
2) Should the domain I want to use on the external internet be added to the host file?
3) What role can bind9 play in this overall setup?

Comment: when you first install from USB, it's easiest to just name it the FQDN.  like foo.brucemwhealton.us in this case.  you can have foo, bar and baz that way.   By the way, you need to configure apache, your website doesn't display properly.  For apache, you could name **one** machine `www.brucemwhealton.us` so that all www traffic goes there... :)